# Some Tailwind CSS classes doesn´t work on my Angular 16 project

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, tailwind-3, daisyui, angular16

I am developing an Angular 16 project with Tailwind CSS V3 installed. I have followed [the official docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular) and it seems everything works; but I can´t understand why some classes work and others not.

For example, I can have this piece of code, trying to set the color of my test:

```
<div class="text-red-500 font-bold">
  this text is supposed to be red and bold
</div>
```

the text displayed will have the font weight bold but the color will not be red color and i always have to edit it using traditionnal scss
Thanks for taking a look on this.

I add the code of the styles.scss , tailwind.config and package.json

styles.scss

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300&display=swap');

:root {
  --gray-color: #979797;
  --primary-green: #05bf95;
}

Tailwind config file:
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
}
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "position-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "pretty-quick": "pretty-quick"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^16.0.1",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^16.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.5",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/maplibre-gl": "^1.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.9",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "daisyui": "^3.0.23",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ngrx": "^2.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the style applied but overridden, or not present at all ? Try providing a [mcve] of your issue

Comment: it's not present at all, like if the class doesn't exist in tailwind

Comment: Try re-installing tailwind then

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i found the solution, my code was overwritten by Daisy Ui. after uninstall it, everything start working fine